# How can I call python scripts on a remote server from z/OS?

Tags: python, mainframe, jcl

As part of migrating batch jobs (and used EXEC PGM) to other language (python here), facing challenge in cross server connection.

We are targeting to migrate few of our mainframes batch jobs COBOL programs to python. In this process, some batch jobs will be fully controlled using schedulers and programs will be rewrite in python scripts. But some mainframes programs will remain intact and not be migrated in python for now. As we are targeting partial migration for now, some mainframe batch jobs need to call python scripts on cloud. I am facing challenge here, how to call python scripts from mainframe batch jobs.

Comment: What have you tried?  What research have you done?  What capabilities does the cloud host you're using have?  As is, this is unanswerable.

Comment: I looked for some solution and came across calling remote script  using REXEC. But haven't tried yet on this as not sure whether I am right path or not.What capabilities are required in cloud for successful connection,  please suggest. Thanks!

Comment: Why are you not running the Python scripts directly on the mainframe?

Comment: @cschneid: We are in the process of migrating from z/os to cloud.

Comment: Where are your python scripts? in mainframe or outside mainframe?

Comment: It's outside mainframes and is planned to be on Google cloud platform.

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming in this answer the COBOL applications run on the z/OS operating system on your mainframe, but if that assumption is not correct, please post a follow-up.

Cschneid has a great answer: just run the Python scripts on your mainframe. Python for z/OS is available for download free of charge from Rocket Software here:

https://www.rocketsoftware.com/zos-open-source

You can optionally purchase Python support on z/OS from Rocket Software if you wish. (All Linux distributions for IBM Z machines also include Python, typically supported by the Linux distributor.) Python running on IBM Z can directly operate on IBM Z-based data stores/databases, including well protected, z/OS-encrypted data sets. And you can quite easily create and manage hybrid cloud architectures that include IBM Z resources across all operating systems. That'd be the best arrangement all around since otherwise you're likely to have operational and management issues. You don't have to look very far to find real world instances of organizations that have suffered major, hugely business impactful batch scheduling problems that have completely wrecked their payment processes, for example. (Relatedly, Python is not an enterprise job scheduler.)

OK, that said, if you're still going to proceed down this (probably unwise) path this way, then here are some other options in no particular order:

1. Configure z/OS Management Facility (included as a base, included, supported feature in z/OS), and use its authorized REST APIs to submit jobs. Details are available here (z/OS 2.4 asssumed, but this feature is available in all currently supported z/OS releases and even prior):

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSLTBW_2.4.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r4.izua700/IZUHPINFO_API_RESTJOBS.htm

Make sure you take reasonable, appropriate steps to secure this job submission path since it's quite powerful.

2. Equip your z/OS installation with IBM's z/OS Connect Enterprise Edition software product, create the REST APIs you need (both easy and powerful), and invoke them from Python. More information on z/OS Connect EE is available here:

https://www.ibm.com/us-en/marketplace/connect-enterprise-edition

3. If you have MQ for z/OS, then go grab the MQ client, send an appropriately formatted MQ message from Python to an appropriately configured MQ queue on z/OS, and invoke/trigger your programs that way. (MQ Advanced for z/OS is recommended for Advanced Message Security.) The MQ clients are free for unlimited use when connecting to all currently IBM supported, licensed versions of MQ and MQ Advanced for z/OS. Recent releases of MQ and MQ Advanced for z/OS also support REST APIs (and JSON payloads), so you can format your messages that way now. MQ clients are available for download here:

https://developer.ibm.com/messaging/mq-downloads/

At least some of the choices I'm providing on this list can be combined with MQ, which provides assured messaging -- which is quite helpful if you're trying to make this all work robustly.

4. Go find out what enterprise job scheduler your mainframe has installed (it probably has one), and use its authorized APIs to schedule and to run programs. For example, IBM Z Workload Scheduler provides authorized REST APIs. Refer to this documentation for an introduction:

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSRULV_9.5.0/com.ibm.tivoli.itws.doc_9.5/common/src_dgd/awsddrestapi.htm

If you click through to the samples you'll find some Python sample code.

....And there are lots of other possible ways, so if for some reason you don't like any of these choices, please post a follow-up.

Comment: Thanks @Timothy for this detailed answer. But all options are for calling Cobol program on z/OS from Python. My requirement is to call Python script from batch job on z/OS. Please let me know if there is anything confusing in question which made you think other way round.

Answer (score 2):

Cschneid has another reasonable answer: Dovetailed's Co:Z Toolkit ("z/OS Hybrid Batch"). Here are some more possibilities, in no particular order:

1. The z/OS Client Web Enablement Toolkit, an included, IBM supported feature in the base z/OS operating system. This toolkit allows you to call a REST API from practically any program on z/OS. A COBOL sample is available here:

https://github.com/IBM/zOS-Client-Web-Enablement-Toolkit

2. z/OS Connect Enterprise Edition, which is bidirectional.
3. The enterprise job scheduler often installed and hosted on z/OS typically can trigger and manage "remote" tasks on other systems. IBM Z Workload Scheduler (for example) certainly can, and there's a whole manual discussing the topic here:

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSRULV_9.5.0/com.ibm.tivoli.itws.doc_9.5/eqqlwmst.pdf

4. Remote Procedure Calls (RPC), per IETF RFCs 1831 and 1832. If you're using a COBOL program with RPC you'd call the C interfaces, a minor bit of mixed language programming.

Comment: Thanks @Timothy for providing number of possible options that will certainly will help me trying things at broad level.

Answer (score 1):

Dovetailed Technologies [hybrid batch](https://www.dovetail.com/products/hybridbatch.html) is another product that allows you to execute code residing on remote servers as steps in a batch job, similar to the solutions in the answers posted by @TimothySipples and @KevinMcKenzie.

Comment: Thanks @cschneid. Hybrid batch certainly looks good option here.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing more, this question is impossible to answer.

However, generically speaking, you can issue USS commands from batch, using [bpxbatch](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSLTBW_2.4.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r4.bpxa400/xbat.htm).  So, you could install something like curl or wget from [Rocket Software](https://www.rocketsoftware.com/product-categories/mainframe/curl-for-zos), and then call python via a REST API, or something similar on the cloud end, built in Django or Flask.  If you really wanted to do something horrible, you could write a shell script that would ssh in to the cloud system, and issue a command on the remote system.

However, and I realize you probably don't have much say over this, I'd also point to Timothy Sipples' answer, and say this isn't a good idea, and it's going to be fragile.  You'll need multiple such scripts, because you'll need to submit work, and then come back later and get the results, and behave appropriately based on the results.  You're going to have to build all sorts of error handling capabilities into these batch jobs/shell scripts.

Comment: Yes @Kevin,  I am not sure at this point of time about the whole approach that we are going to use as we are first exploring the feasibility of the same before proceeding with some concrete step. As this can impact existing batch processing. But certainly all the options provided give Ray of hope to proceed in this direction, obviously with some cautions.